# Reading values from raster, and creating column of those values in Attribute Table of shapefile?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, polygon, attribute-table

I have a map of polygons from a shapefile which lost its numbered labels in the conversion process from .pdf to .shp. In order to make these labels visible again, I creased a raster from a .png file, and georeferenced this layer onto its identical polygon layer.

My goal is to create a column of values in the Attribute Table of the polygon layer that includes the label from the raster layer for each specific polygon. Is there a simple way to auto-fill this column? Although the labels are numbers, the labels can be read as text to prevent any formatting error that could arise.

I need the polygons to have the labels from the raster layer because I have information (land-use, price, etc.) for each polygon based on these labels.

In the attached screenshot below, the selected polygon has ID "2917" and should have its CTS column filled with the value/string "1572/8".

[image: Small part of the map with polygon ID of "2917" with CTS column to be read as "1572/8"]

Comment: I also have the original map with the plot CTS labels in a PDF, as well as an .svg file if either of those file type would make this process easier.

Answer (score 1):

To do this will take some effort.

I think you would need to start with [Optical Character Recognition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition) but even when you can get the characters as text you will need to perform some sort of spatial join to get the text into the attribute table of the features.